# How to disable scrolling in overlay window?

Tags: jquery, overlay, toggle

I am fairly new to jQuery and I have this overlay window that pops up when a user clicks a button:

```
    function toggleOverlay() {
    $("#overlay").animate({
        opacity: 'toggle',
        height: 'toggle',
    });
}
```

My problem is that I need to prevent the user from scrolling the page somehow while the overlay is being shown.

I tried something like

```
overflow: 'toggle',
```

but it's not working.

How can this be done?

You can see a working example of my form here: [Link to website](https://www.designbits.de/kontakt). Just click on "Rundbrief abonnieren" and the form pops up. I want to disable the scrolling though. How can it be done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want disable scroll for all or just want overlay to cover whole page, when scrolling too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about setting overflow to hidden?

also i couldn't find your button in the link you provided, it shows here though http://2012.designbits.de/kontakt/

Comment: Yes, my apologies. [This](http://2012.designbits.de/kontakt) is the correct page with the button.

Comment: Are you sure? I made a test and ´$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");´ works ok, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is not possible. Try to use this [plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html). It looks more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry my answer isn't really fitting your question. You could make the #overlay and #signup with `position: fixed`, so the background won't be seen.

(Und ich glaube, du wolltest http://2012.designbits.de/kontakt/ verlinken... ;-)

Comment: Yes, sorry indeed my link was a little misleading.

Comment: ´position: fixed´ does help a lot indeed. Thanks so much! It is close to perfect now, but the page can still be scrolled a little. Not sure if there's any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Jquery Block UI** Plugin which Blocks a Part of the UI or The Complete UI until unblocked.
Then Block the UI  while the overlay is being shown. 
Do not Forget to **Unblock** the UI after the  overlay is shown. Here is the [link to Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block)